How to interpret addEventListener ("change", ... code
I'm new to javascript and do not understand the following code snippet after searching for "[javascript] add.EventListener("change", " on both stackoverflow and the web. As I understand what I've read, one deals with an HTML change event as follows:
addEventListener("change", (event) => {});

Presumably, 'event' is the method invoked to deal with the change, but I do not understand what is meant by () => ternary operation in the below code. It looks like no function is being called. So what then is meant by =>?
Below is the code snippet I'm trying to understand.
const select = document.querySelector("select");
const html = document.querySelector("html");
document.body.style.padding = "10px";

function update(bgColor, textColor) {
  html.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  html.style.color = textColor;
}

select.addEventListener("change", () =>
  select.value === "black"
    ? update("black", "white")
    : update("white", "black"),
);

I understand the ternary operator and so know that if the value is "black" then the update function is called with ("black", "white").
As stated above, I searched here and with google.

the => is an arrow function. it is saying is when the select elements are changed, check to see if the value is black and if it is call update('black','white') and if not call update('white','black').

its the same as 

Are you just asking about the arrow function? This is really just code that could (should) be written in a clearer way. Personally I cannot stand using a ternary like this

IMO it would be much clearer as () => { if (select.value === 'black') { update('black', 'white'); } else { update('white', 'black'); } }

Thanks for answers. I'm asking about () and =>. Am I correct that () just means no function is being called? thanks

@LadyofLA it's a function with an empty arguments list. To help explain, these are equivalent... () => { ... } and function() { ... }, and so are these... (event) => { ... } and function(event) { ... }
